# Limit query size for specific users

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

Is there a way to limit the rows returned for a user in Oracle.

We have some users than can query some tables with millions of records decreasing the performance of the database, so I would like to know if there someway to set max size of records per user.

For example, If I have the table: APP.HISTORY with 10,000,000 records and the user 'dummy', I would like to set for dummy user that can only read 10,000 records from it.

For example if 'dummy' execute:

```
select * from APP.HISTORY
```

It will only return 10,000 records, instead try to fetch the 10,000,000 records

Comment: You could maybe use [Resource Groups](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25494/dbrm.htm#ADMIN027) to limit CPU or other activity, but # rows would maybe require views of some sorts.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't any built-in functionality to limit the number of results per user.

However, even if you could, that wouldn't necessarily help you resolve your performance concern.

Consider for example a query like:

```
select *
  from (select *
          from app.history
         order by some_field desc)
 where rownum < 2
```

According to your requirements, user `dummy` would be able to run this and get back the single result he's interested in. However, assuming `some_field` is not indexed, then, even though this query will return a single record, it still has to order all `10,000,000` records to produce that single row.

As suggested by `OldProgrammer` in the comments, consider using resource groups, which is a very flexible and configurable way of throttling CPU and I/O usage.

Otherwise, if you don't trust user `dummy` to write smart and efficient queries, then don't give him direct access to the database.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, we have an old reported (OpenReport) and there are a lot records retrieving huge data, hanging the app server, decreasing the performance from the database, this Open Report have the connection configuration, I was thinking to restrict the user that we are using on it.